# What's the simplest way to create a facebook frontend-javascript authentification (for a facebook app)?

Tags: facebook

In the facebook/connect-js, there are some really neat features like "FB.login" for logging in and FB.logout, for logging out, is there something similair for authentification for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use FB.login to get the authentication.

```
        FB.login(function(response) {
        var access_token = response.session.access_token;
            if (response.session) {
                if (response.perms) {
                  // user is logged in, everithig is ok                     
                } else {
                  // user is logged in, but did not grant any permissions
        }
              } else {
                // user is not logged in
      }
        }, {perms:'read_stream,publish_stream,offline_access'});
```